# loopbackjs: how to get specifics parents filtering related model

Tags: loopbackjs

like a common joined relation i would like to filter my results based on filtered children in a parent-child relation.
i did this

```
{"include":{"relation":"children","scope":{"where":{"and":[{"name":"xxx"}]}}}}
```

that gave me ALL parents and inside them, children filtered by that name.

any clues? thanks

ref: 
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+related+models#Queryingrelatedmodels-Usingfiltersparameterswithincludedrelations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/32933383/344022 there's nothing officially available yet. There is a [fork of the loopback-connector](https://github.com/DiogoDoreto/loopback-connector/wiki) by @DiogoDoreto that does attempt to provide it. I haven't tried it, but if you were to use it you would do the following in a filter:

```
  "where": {
    "children": {
      "where": {
        "name": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks also, we have to wait fo .. ref: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517

Comment: @gustavomick this is referred to in my linked SO answer. Also see DiogoDoreto's comment on Oct 16 from that issue. That's where I found the answer to your question, so you may not need to wait if you can use the fork :-)