# nodeJS loopback include filter

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

i have a problem with Node JS loop-back include filter when i make a query .Every time its giving all records in response.but i want only those records that holds the `sportid` which  i am passing in query filter.

```
 var request = {
     method: 'get',
     command: 'UserPersonalinfos',
     query: {
         filter: {
             "include": {
                 "relation": "UserRegistration",
                  "where": {
                      "sportid": data[0].id
                  }
             },
             limit:5
          }
     },
     headers: {
         access_token:userAccessToken.id,
     }
 };
```

if `sportid` exists then it should return object otherwise it should not, but in this case its returns all `UserPersonalinfos` records and adding `UserRegistration` object to `UserPersonalinfos` object

Comment: simply i want only those records in response those have sport id otherwise they should not be in response if record don't have sportid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LoopbackJS: HasAndBelongsToMany, how to query/filter by property of relation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903293/loopbackjs-hasandbelongstomany-how-to-query-filter-by-property-of-relation)

Answer (score 0):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/32933383/344022 there's nothing officially available yet. [There is a fork of the loopback-connector by @DiogoDoreto](https://github.com/DiogoDoreto/loopback-connector/wiki) that does attempt to provide it. I haven't tried it, but if you were to use it you would do the following in a filter:

```
  "where": {
    "UserRegistration": {
      "where": {
        "sportid": data[0].id
      }
    }
  }
```

The answer linked above also suggests some other ways of achieving what you want.

Comment: Am guessing you didn't get the fork code from the link?

Comment: the link says that first i have to  make a query in 'UserRegistration' for those records who have 'data[0].id'.then i have to make a query to 'UserPersonalinfos'  for  these ids but i don't won't to do additional work.because i am using limit in query and i made query for client side then if i sends limit 10 i want 10 records.and i want to do this task by a query . it is possible ???

Comment: Unfortunately AFAIK the only way you can really achieve what you want is by following the link to the pull request from that answer, and trying that. Here is a more direct link: https://github.com/DiogoDoreto/loopback-connector/wiki

Comment: It mentions about creation of sql queries, is it also for MongoDB?

Comment: It looks like MongoDB is supported, from reading the comments. I haven't tried it myself though.