# Pass an already existing Model to next in Loopback

Tags: express, model, foreign-keys, loopbackjs

There is `Project` model

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "plural": "Projects",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "code": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "startDate": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    },
    "endDate": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "value": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "infoEN": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "infoRU": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "infoAM": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "externalLinks": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "industry": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Industry",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    },
    "service": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Service",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    },
    "tags": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Tag",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

And it `hasAndBelongsToMany` tags

here is `Tag` model

```
{
  "name": "Tag",
  "plural": "Tags",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Now when the relation is created loopback api gives this api endpoint.

```
POST /Projects/{id}/tags
```

This creates a new tag into the tags collection and adds it to the project.
But what about adding an already existing tag to the project?

So I figured maybe I add `before save` hook to the `Tag`
Here I'll check if the tag exists and then pass the existing one for the relation.

Something like this.

`tag.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Tag) {
  Tag.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
    console.log(ctx.instance);
    Tag.find({name: ctx.instance.name})
    next();
  });
  // Tag.validatesUniquenessOf('name', {message: 'name is not unique'});
};
```

Comment: both different api you can not merge 2 api if you use relation then you will get some default relational  api of both like get post in project api. however if you want to use tag in project you can use something like this app.models.tag in your project to use tag model inside project

Comment: @bipin will you please give some example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tags relationship in loopback 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375808/tags-relationship-in-loopback-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HaykSafaryan it just demo to show you how to use tag  inside project

```
var app = require('../../server/server');
module.exports = function(project) {
 var tag=app.models.tags
 //afterremote it just demo. you can use any method
 project.afterRemote('create', function(ctx, next) { 
 tag.find({name: ctx.instance.name},function(err,result)){
 if(err) throw err; 
  next()
 }    
 });
};
```

this is just example code to show you how to use update,create ,find ,upsertwithwhere etc. tag for validation you have to setup condition over here it will not take validation which you defined in tags models